# Pass only object id or whole object to method

Tags: ruby, performance

I have a class `Foo` connected to a database, and a method `bar` that accepts one argument with two possible specifications and implementations:

```
class Foo
  def bar(object_id)
    object = Object.find(object_id)
    object.do_something
  end
end
```

and

```
class Foo
  def bar(object)
    object.do_something
  end
end
```

Should I pass `object.id` and load the object from the database, or pass the whole `object` just loaded? Which approach is better? Does it matter for performance?

Comment: It all depends. Do you already have the object loaded? Is the parameter going to be serialized (if Foo is an sidekiq worker, for example)? In general, passing the object is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not doing it via sidekiq or other form of serialization, you should simply pass an object - it will end up in memory anyway, so you avoid unnecessary DB query and you make your class less dependent on `Object` implementation.

Comment: Less dependencies/coupling too

Comment: @MarekLipka Thanks for the answer. I am not calling it via Sidekiq, but what if I would?

Comment: @sampi: then you don't want to pass the object (unless it's [GlobalID](https://github.com/rails/globalid)-capable).